# Any way whatsoever to get font expansion in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, microtype, font-expansion

I have recently switched to XeLaTeX from LuaLaTeX for various reasons, and am missing microtype’s font expansion. Is there a way (any way whatsoever) that this can be achieved, **even if it is unstable** (an alpha perhaps – I think I remember finding a page for downloading an alpha microtype with XeLaTeX font expansion, but I can’t find it any more), hacky (defining commands with XeLaTeX equivalents to LuaLaTeX/PDFLaTeX commands inside, i.e. emulation), or **even if it doesn’t work all the time**.

**Please just answer with any way that even *partially* works.**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think that there is anything, at least I don't remember. The only extension towards microtype was protrusion. Why don't you want to use lualatex anymore?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see the edited post

Comment: My question wasn't mean as critic. I really want to know what is missing. If you have concrete examples of problems, add them e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454031/2388, or a my github account. But beside this: it is your choice, but imho xelatex won't in the near feature offer font expansion.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, sorry that my reply came across that way . I don’t specifically have any examples of ‘bad’ rendering in LuaLaTeX – it is just sort of an aside. I guess maybe you are right – although I will first try getting better justification in XeLaTeX by tweaking some parameters though. Hopefully I will be able to get back to the standard LuaLaTeX and font expansion set, but I doubt it.