# Bangla breaks apart with lualatex!

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode, arabluatex

I switched to `lualatex` for coloring part of Arabic words easily with `arabluatex` and `xcolor`. With xelatex I'd no problem with Bangla.

Here's the latex script:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{arabluatex, fontspec, xcolor}
\setmainfont{[Kalpurush]}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Al Qalam Quran Majeed Web} 

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}     % Arabic inside LTR
\newcommand{\n}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}     % for digits inside Arabic text
\newcommand{\afootnote}[1]{\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}     % Arabic footnotes
\newenvironment{Arabic}{\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}     % Arabic paragraph

\def\r{\color{red}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}    

    কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে? \\
    \textarabic{وَ{\r لَ}دٌ}\\
    \textarabic{{\r ٱل}كَلَمُ}\\
    \textarabic{أَبَ{\r كُم}}

\end{document}
```

and here's the output:

[image]

Bangla output in the first line should have been:  কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে?

How to fix Bangla in lualatex?

Comment: Thanks. @UlrikeFischer The glyphs look kind of familiar, I think we had some similar problem in luaotfload before. Do you remember anything about it?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, not all Arabic fonts work with arabluatex for coloring parts! `Traditional Arabic` doesn't work at all, with `Simplified Arabic` it works to some extent but alphabets actually get disunified, with `Arabic Typesetting` it doesn't work well! I found `Al Qalam Quran Majeed Web` in an article and so far it's working nicely.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger The script is also mentioned here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454031/examples-for-broken-rendering-of-scripts-in-lualatex. Imho (as it fails in context too) it is one of the cases why we want harfbuzz in luatex (with mode=harf it works fine).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, harfbuzz is for Arabic, right? I don't have any issue with Arabic, it's working nicely. My problem is with Bangla.

Comment: no, harfbuzz is a library for all scripts (and harfbuzz is used in xetex where your script works fine).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, in `xelatex` Arabic broke apart, I'd tried this code.

Comment: well if you are feeling adventurous you could try harftex (which is luatex + harfbuzz).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I'm using Latex Workshop in Visual Studio Code. I just changed `pdf` to `xe` or `lua` in `settings` to make it work for me and it did perfectly, but `harf` isn't working in VS Code! I've `MikTex 2.9` installed in my System.

Comment: harftex isn't in miktex. You would need a texlive and then get the binaries from http://w32tex.org/ (and you would need to make a latex format for it, and get https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for your info. Installing `harftex` seems very complicated!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I've removed MikTex and installed TexLive 2019 and everything seems to be working  fine, without downloading and installing binaries from w32tex.org, in VS Code with  Latex Workshop except that I've to copy some of arabic fonts in my working directory, eg. Al Qalam Quran Majeed Web. If I use Simplified Arabic, Traditional Arabic, etc. I don't have to put a copy of these in working directory. Now I've [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493180/how-to-install-harftex-on-texlive) question!

Comment: November 2019 update on how to run the luaharfbuzz engine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493180/how-to-install-harftex-on-texlive

Answer (score 2):

Compile with the luahbtex engine.

[image: bengali conjuncts]

The example uses fonts I have available.

The Harfbuzz font shaping engine (now in luatex) knows how to form conjuncts.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{arabluatex, fontspec, xcolor}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Bengali]%[Kalpurush]}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Noto Sans Arabic}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Arabic]%[Script = Arabic]{Al Qalam Quran Majeed Web} 

\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}     % Arabic inside LTR
\newcommand{\n}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TLT #1\egroup}     % for digits inside Arabic text
\newcommand{\afootnote}[1]{\footnote{\textarabic{#1}}}     % Arabic footnotes
\newenvironment{Arabic}{\textdir TRT\pardir TRT\arabicfont}{}     % Arabic paragraph

\def\r{\color{red}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}    

    কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে? \\
    \textarabic{وَ{\r لَ}دٌ}\\
    \textarabic{{\r ٱل}كَلَمُ}\\
    \textarabic{أَبَ{\r كُم}}

\end{document}
```

Because I have MiKTeX on Windows, and I like to run latex, I set up a compiler option using `miktex-luahblatex.exe`.

Refer to the instructions in: [How to install HarfTeX on TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493180/how-to-install-harftex-on-texlive), "Update November 2019" section. (You don't need to install HarfTex anymore.)